Can a trombone sound as brittle as in *f* dynamics, yet as quiet as in *mf*?
In my music editor, the trombone sounds very different in mp and mf dynamics compared to f dynamics. In mf, it has a soft quality—almost like a French horn—and mp is nearly the same, just a bit quieter. However, when I switch to f, it starts sounding exactly like a real trombone, with that common sandy and brittle timbre. The problem is that it also becomes much louder than mf. I solve this in my editor by simply reducing the velocity (volume) level.
But what about in real life? Can a trombone produce that characteristic brittle sound without being loud, maintaining the volume of mf dynamics?

I'm not a good enough brass player to say for sure, but the general principle is true. Many instruments can do multiple timbres for a given dynamic. Virtual instruments often simplify this, or you have a noticeable change in timbre at some volume point.

Someone else can probably explain the science behind it better but as just about any instrument gets louder the timbre begins to change and get brighter with a sharper attack. This probably has to do with the intensity of the vibrations producing the sound which bring out more of the higher overtones. There is a certain amount of control an experienced player has over this but in the case of trombone I don’t believe you can get a super bright brassy sound out of a “p” dynamic or a super sweet French horn like sound out of a “ff”.


But what about in real life? Can a trombone produce that characteristic brittle sound without being loud, maintaining the volume of mf dynamics?

I'm not sure exactly what you mean by sandy and brittle.  If you are looking for a brassy sound that penetrates the texture but isn't quite as loud as f dynamic, you could specify the trombonist use a straight mute.  In my experience (as a trombone player) this gives an edgier sound.
More importantly, don't trust your editor to render the trombone accurately - even the good ones miss a lot.  Instead, find yourself a bone player nearby.  Depending on genre, you might look around at a local university with a music program, or head to a few jazz band concerts (or whatever style you're looking for).  I can almost guarantee that he/she will gladly spend an hour with you and give you a real picture of what the instrument is capable of in exchange for a beer/coffee.

To a certain degree this can be influenced by selection of the type of trombone. The main parameter is the bore size of the trombone. Modern large bore orchestral trombones are very loud while jazz type small bore trombones make less decibels for the same sound.
Examples of orchestral music includes English orchestral music before about 1930 was written for small bore trombones. When played on large bore instruments, the dynamic notations will be, well, too forte.
